# redirect curl output to dynamic filename every 5 minutes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, curl

Can I redirect the output stream from curl which is displayed on the stdout to a dynamic filename. I want to establish a connection to a server using curl then redirect the output of the command to a filename every 5 minutes (without disconnecting the connection and re-establish it again).

I tried this but did not work

```
curl ..... | tee -a "$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M).txt"
```

Comment: That calculates the filename once when the `tee` process starts. To do what you want you need to send the output to something that calculates the output file location for every line of output. You could do this with awk or perl/etc.

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried curl ... | awk '{print $0}' > "$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M).txt" but this did not work.

Comment: @PyQL Of course it doesn't, you're still redirecting the output in the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work better:

```
curl ..... | \
    awk '{
        newtime = systime()
        if (newtime > oldtime + 300) {
            if (fname)
                close(fname)
            oldtime = newtime
            fname = strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M.txt", oldtime)
        }
        print >>fname
        print
    }'
```